# I am sending the table cell as slot values to controller from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am sending the table cell slot values to controller from jsp. I am using tag for table how to get vallue of div in Spring controller. my data is coming from data after making it filter.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: As we can't  get the value by request.getParmeter("divID");

Comment: Yes, you can't but there's some workaround to do it, for example a form with hidden inputs and a submit button.

Comment: code currently I don't have.There is a lot of cell So if we use of hidden form input it will be taking more loading time there is around 1800 cells.

Comment: @SanjayGupta a simple javascript can do that

Comment: @ user5266804 can u suggest me  by some raw code